# automatic post data from other web to odoo

Tags: python, api, odoo, odoo-11, xmlrpcclient

I have to get data from other web using python and post that data to `odoo`, is that possible?

I already tried to create records in python like documentation in `odoo`, but I don't think it can automatically, my goal is to post data from that web to `odoo` automatically, but my problem I don't know how to post data to `odoo` automatically, please help me

Answer (score -2):

Maybe Selenium can help you
Selenium is automates browsers that support Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox ... etc
You can send keys and click button, other all things.

odoo login example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapwrap"]/header/div/div/div/a').click() // click the SIGN IN button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, //*[@id="login"]))) // wait the login page
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]').send_keys('your id') // send your id the web
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys('your pw') // send your pw the web
```